# Add Echo in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

underneath is a small script which shows if someone has a birthday today. 
The only thing what i miss is a line under the name with the text "Happy birthday" It should only appear, ofcourse is someone has a birthday. how can i achieve this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vandaag Jarig:</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "****");
        if (!$connect) {
            die(mysql_error());

        }
        mysql_select_db("my_site_db");
        $results = mysql_query
("SELECT * FROM aevinew2_verjaardagen WHERE DAY(geboortedatum) = DAY    (CURDATE ()) AND MONTH(geboortedatum) = MONTH(CURDATE())");
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Naam']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Afdeling']?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
}else{
echo "Helaas geen taart vandaag, er is niemand jarig";
}
        ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would comparing todays date vs the date in the DB not work?

Comment: Where is problem? In SQL query you have condition to birthday and current date, it doesn't work? I mean everybody who is returned by this query, has BD today (no other names are returned).

Comment: dont use `mysql_*` functions - is deprecated, instead use http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: seconding what @JosefDrábek says - do ***NOT*** use MySQL but instead move on to MySQLi or PDO - with some minor adjustments these will take you forward. MySQL (standard) is **deprecated** and no longer supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You had syntax error in your code aswell. Missing ; delimiter at end of echo command.

```
<td><?php echo $row['Naam'].'<br/>Happy Birthday!'; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Afdeling']; ?></td>
```

Comment: Using this, shows me for each record (in case 2 or more people van Birthday) the text. It should only appears once

Comment: has been solved with this code:

    <?php
    echo "\n\32";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<strong>";
    echo "Van harte gefeliciteerd!";
    echo "</strong>";
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 22 ,23 with these lines. You are missing ';' after echo statement.

```
<td><?php echo $row['Naam'].'<br/>Happy Birthday!'; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Afdeling']; ?></td>
```

Comment: It is not required, but you should put it, as a good practice.have you tried using this solution? i was having same kind of issu , this solution worked for mine .see that for delimeter seperation http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Answer (score 0):

well, the script is working (it was already), but the only thing i need is an echo under the current echo which is just showing some text.

If i do that it letterly puts that kind of text on top include the text Echo